# Can not format read only usb disk

Tags: partitioning, usb, format, read-only

My USB drive spontaneously changed to read only mode. I can't do any thing with it, even though I did not boot from it. I tried to change from read only mode by this command:

```
 sudo hdparm -r0 /media/mahdi/1C4F-0BFD

And I get this error:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 BLKROSET failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
 BLKROGET failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I also tried with change `sudo chmod 777 /dev/sdc1`

It seems successfully done without any error but result is nothing. My disk is still read-only.

I googled and fin **Gparted**. Any change format or delete partition gets error.[image]
As you see in image there is a lock icon beside derive name.
I tried for formatting and even deleting. All actions get error.

Comment: The "lock" just means it's mounted, you can't delete partitions of a drive while it's mounted.

Comment: The permanent read only state may well be a sign of malfunction, as detected by the controller inside the usb-device - assuming it is FLASH-memory based.

Comment: @guillermochamorro. Deleting was one of my tries. So what do you recommend? How i can reformat it?

Comment: @Hannu Suddenly it changed to read only mode.

Comment: @K7AAY No I did not boot from the flash.

Comment: @Kenji Please open a terminal, run `sudo umount /dev/sdc` because, as you can see in the Mount Point column of gparted, the drive is mounted. You have to unmount it to change it. If you are not able to change it after unmounting it, please click [edit] and let us know. Please Do Not use Add Comment; instead, please use -----> [edit] <-------

Comment: @Kenji Do you mean, with gparted and the USB *unmounted* you couldn't delete the partition? Some error appeared?

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) can help you analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve it.

Comment: This has happened to me a few times, in each case the drive was dead. It is a nice feature that the drive sometimes remains readable, if not writable. First case used Persistent SD as a server, It became useless after 6 months, second time used another SD card as a server, this time booting into RAM, it became read only in 6 months but still works fine as a server.